# Ruby Range printing out extra

Tags: ruby, range

I'm new to coding so please free to point out any errors in the way I refer to code.

```
rows = 5
 (1..rows).each do |n|
  print n, ' '
end
```

This prints out what I expect it to: `1 2 3 4 5`.

But, when I put it into a method:

```
def test(rows)
  (1..rows).each do |n|
   print n, ' '
 end
end

puts test(5)
```

I get `1 2 3 4 5 1..5`.

Why does the `1..5` show up? And how do I get rid of it?

I need it in the method because I plan to add more code to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Ruby function will return the last statement, in your case `1..5`. To illustrate I'll give it a different return value:

```
def test(rows)
  (1..rows).each {|n| puts "#{ n } "}
  return 'mashbash'
end

# Just the function invokation, only the function will print something
test(5) # => "1 2 3 4 5 "

# Same as above, plus printing the return value of test(5)
puts test(5) # => "1 2 3 4 5 mashbash"
```

You could write your example a little differently to achieve what you like:

```
def second_test(rows)
  # Cast range to an array
  array = (1..rows).to_a # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  array.join(', ') # "1, 2, 3, 4, 5", and it is the last statement => return value
end

# Print the return value ("1, 2, 3, 4, 5") from the second_test function
p second_test(5) 
# => "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

`each` on a Range returns the range after the looping is done, and you're probably printing the return value of `test` too.

Just run `test(5)` instead of `puts test(5)` or something.

Comment: thanks but why does the 1..5 show up when I use `puts`? I thought the return value of test would just be the range itself.

Comment: Yes, and the range is `1..5`, so you get `1..5` as output.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby always returns the last line of any function.

You are executing `puts test(5)`, and `test(5)` prints the data you expect, and the extra `puts` prints out the data returned by `test(5)` method.

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The final `1..5` is the return value from the script. You get that when you run the code in IRB. When you run that as a standalone Ruby script, it will not show up, so you do not need to worry about it.